# Is there a way to restore the undo/redo change history it in Notepad++?

Tags: notepad++, restore, undo-redo

I have been looking for a way to restore my undo/redo stack history in Nodepad++ after closing the program and reopening it. Of course I can restore the session, but I can undo any change to any file after starting the program again. In fact I don't know if this option exists but it looks like basic to me.
If this feature doesn't exist is there a plug in that would make it functional?

Comment: I would recommend posting a question in notepad++'s community website

Comment: Done, thank you. I'll repost here the answers.

Answer (score 1):

The answer in 
https://notepad-plus-plus.org/community/topic/14630/is-there-a-way-to-restore-the-undo-redo-change-history-it-in-notepad
was

Introduction: i’m not a dev but a long time np++ user

unfortunately there is no save state or snapshot option that can resume all undo/redo functions in notepad++ after a reboot or np++ program shutdown at the moment.

this feature request would be theoretically a nice thing, because it would allow to reboot or quit notepad++ and at reopening toggle through all changes that i’ve forgotten since the last work on the opened files, allowing to skip documenting all the changes made before the reboot.